# MySQL - Find the time difference between ROW - LAG and LEAD not working

Tags: mysql

I have a table as follow  on the image [screenshot of my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5ZRB.png)

```
customer_id   purchase_date     Difference between purchases (in days) 
                                     = WHAT I AM TRYING TO GET
1             23/04/2017        0 (first )row
1             24/04/2017        1
1             01/01/2018        252
2             03/05/2017        0 (this is a new customer)
2             10/05/2017        7
```

I want to calculate the time difference between two purchases for the same customer. I tried using the LAG and LEAD functions, but I get syntax error that I do not understand

For now I have been doing this:

```
SELECT customer_id, purchase_date
case 
when lag(purchase_date,1,0) over (partition by customer_id order by 
purchase_date) = 0 then 0
ELSE purchase_date -lag(purchase_date,1,0) over(partition by customer_id order 
by purchase_date) 
end 
FROM
Table1
```

It gives me a syntax error that I dont understand just after the first "over"

Comment: MySQL 8.0+ will support window functions like LAG and LEAD.. in older MySQL versions you can simulate LAG and LEAD functions with MySQL user variables or by using co-related subqueries... But these questions have been asked before on Stackoverflow "MySQL LAG" -> https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=MySQL+LAG and "MySQL LEAD" -> https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=MySQL+LEAD

Comment: Add **comma after purchase_date** in select clause, and what is **a.year** ?

Comment: it is supposed to be .purchase_date but still not working.
and i also added the coma, not working

Comment: What is your version of mySql?

Comment: Please update the question after removing syntex errors.

Comment: version is 5.7.21

Comment: See the fist comment, You must need minimum version 8

Comment: Check here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8z3jnQjFMGYCihi7GkWzpG/0

Answer (score 2):

> **Edited 19-10-2019** 
>   Since 19-04-2018 MySQL 8 was released, which is much better then this answer
>   to use MySQL's user variables to emulate/simulate LEAD()/LAG() window functions.  
>  So if
>   possible i advice to update your current MySQL version to MySQL 8 if
>   possible.

Current MySQL versions do not support window functions like LAG and LEAD. 
MySQL 8.0+ which is now a release candidate will support window functions but is not production ready jet.

In current MySQL versions you can simulate LAG with MySQL's user variables or with co-related subqueries.

**Create table/insert data**

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`customer_id` int, `purchase_date` varchar(10))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`customer_id`, `purchase_date`)
VALUES
    (1, '23/04/2017'),
    (1, '24/04/2017'),
    (1, '01/01/2018'),
    (2, '03/05/2017'),
    (2, '10/05/2017')
;
```

The trick with MySQL user variables is it properly initialize them.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
 *
 , (@customer_id := Table1.customer_id) AS init_customer_id_param
 , (@purchase_date := Table1.purchase_date) AS init_purchase_date_param
FROM 
 Table1
CROSS JOIN (
 SELECT
      @customer_id := NULL
   ,  @purchase_date := NULL 
)
 AS init_user_params
```

**Result**

```
| customer_id | purchase_date | @customer_id := NULL | @purchase_date := NULL | init_customer_id_param | init_purchase_date_param |
|-------------|---------------|----------------------|------------------------|------------------------|--------------------------|
|           1 |    23/04/2017 |               (null) |                 (null) |                      1 |               23/04/2017 |
|           1 |    24/04/2017 |               (null) |                 (null) |                      1 |               24/04/2017 |
|           1 |    01/01/2018 |               (null) |                 (null) |                      1 |               01/01/2018 |
|           2 |    03/05/2017 |               (null) |                 (null) |                      2 |               03/05/2017 |
|           2 |    10/05/2017 |               (null) |                 (null) |                      2 |               10/05/2017 |
```

Now you can add the calculation part. 
Keep in mind the order is important the calculation needs to be done before the initialisation of the MySQL's user variables. 
So the MySQL user variables have the previous column value.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
 *
 , (
     CASE
       WHEN (@customer_id = Table1.customer_id)
       THEN DATEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE(purchase_date, "%d/%m/%Y"), STR_TO_DATE(@purchase_date, "%d/%m/%Y"))
     END
   ) AS diff
 , (@customer_id := Table1.customer_id) AS init_customer_id_param
 , (@purchase_date := Table1.purchase_date) AS init_purchase_date_param   
FROM 
 Table1
CROSS JOIN (
 SELECT
      @customer_id := NULL
   ,  @purchase_date := NULL 
)
 AS init_user_params
ORDER BY 
  STR_TO_DATE(purchase_date, "%d/%m/%Y") ASC
```

**Note**

iám using STR_TO_DATE function to format the varchar based dateformat into the datetime format.  
 
If your date column is already is a date datatype you can remove the function and use `THEN DATEDIFF(purchase_date, @purchase_date)` instead.

**Result**

```
| customer_id | purchase_date | @customer_id := NULL | @purchase_date := NULL |   diff | init_customer_id_param | init_purchase_date_param |
|-------------|---------------|----------------------|------------------------|--------|------------------------|--------------------------|
|           1 |    23/04/2017 |               (null) |                 (null) | (null) |                      1 |               23/04/2017 |
|           1 |    24/04/2017 |               (null) |                 (null) |      1 |                      1 |               24/04/2017 |
|           1 |    01/01/2018 |               (null) |                 (null) |    252 |                      1 |               01/01/2018 |
|           2 |    03/05/2017 |               (null) |                 (null) | (null) |                      2 |               03/05/2017 |
|           2 |    10/05/2017 |               (null) |                 (null) |      7 |                      2 |               10/05/2017 |
```

Now it simply selecting the correct columns.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
   Table1_user_params.customer_id 
 , Table1_user_params.purchase_date
 , (
     CASE
       WHEN  Table1_user_params.diff IS NULL
       THEN 0
       ELSE Table1_user_params.diff 
     END 
   ) 
    AS diff
FROM ( 
  SELECT 
   *
   , (
       CASE
         WHEN (@customer_id = Table1.customer_id)
         THEN DATEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE(purchase_date, "%d/%m/%Y"), STR_TO_DATE(@purchase_date, "%d/%m/%Y"))
       END
     ) AS diff
   , (@customer_id := Table1.customer_id) AS init_customer_id_param
   , (@purchase_date := Table1.purchase_date) AS init_purchase_date_param   
  FROM 
   Table1
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT
        @customer_id := NULL
     ,  @purchase_date := NULL 
  )
   AS init_user_params
  ORDER BY 
    STR_TO_DATE(purchase_date, "%d/%m/%Y") ASC
) 
 AS Table1_user_params
```

**Result**

```
| customer_id | purchase_date | diff |
|-------------|---------------|------|
|           1 |    23/04/2017 |    0 |
|           1 |    24/04/2017 |    1 |
|           1 |    01/01/2018 |  252 |
|           2 |    03/05/2017 |    0 |
|           2 |    10/05/2017 |    7 |
```

Comment: thank you really much ! trying to understand it now :) I dit not think the answer would be so complicated, I have some work now

Comment: @mo_att the answer isn't that complicated i could include the co-related subquery approach also if you want and if sqlfiddle.com works again.